# Logout From SSO service on bluemix

Tags: node.js, single-sign-on, ibm-cloud

I have one Node Bluemix application configured with the SSO Service & connected with a Cloud Directory. I can successfully authenticate the user but I'm having problems to accomplish a successful logout. I have tried req.session.destroy, req.logout, and express-passport-logout module to end the session. But none of them worked. I also tried to remove cookies from my application but it didn't work as well. The only way it is working is by restarting the browser or clearing cookies from browser. Does anybody know how to achieve a SSO logout from the application?

Answer (score 1):

The last time I used the service this was not possible. The problem is: what you are doing with the listed commands is to close your application session, not the one on SSO service. So when the user comes back (with the same cookie) your application will ask SSO service to check and it will accept the user (since the session there is still open). Currently there is no API available to close the session on the SSO service instance.

Actually, this becomes more complex when you use external IdP: even if you close the session at the SSO server, the browser will still have a session with the real IdP the user logged in from, which depending on the configuration of your service instance could be one or more of IBM, Facebook, Google, Linkedin. Some of these IdP's provide long-lived sessions via persistent cookies and your application can't force the termination on their side. That means that on next click of the "login" button, particularly in the case where the SSO service instance is configured to use only one IdP, SSO will happen seamlessly with no further interaction.

Take a look [here](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/164923/logout-from-sso-service-on-bluemix.html) to get more information.

Answer (score 0):

As Umberto says, maybe it was not possible before, but now it seems to be:

Check [this](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/SingleSignOn/configure_apps.html#tsk_configuringnodejsapp_express4). You can redirect your user to this:

```
/idaas/mtfim/sps/idaas/logout
```

At least this seems to work if you only use Cloud Directory.